# Angular ngFor carousel from variable

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a carousel that shows pictures from a variable in the .ts. I planned using ngFor.

I have a static Bootstrap 4 carousel:

```
 <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="assets/fortress.jpg" class="d-block w-100 carousel-pic" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="assets/fortress.jpg" class="d-block w-100 carousel-pic" alt="...">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have a variable in the .ts file called **pics**:
[image]

Now I tried putting the ngFor the carousel, and the active carousel just the first picture. Problem:

- The carousel are off. Just showing three. When I try setting the *ngFor* there, it doesn't work.
- Slide shows first picture (active) okay but the second slide show the same picture (because the loop starts again) and then it stops, doesn't show the third picture.

When I tried just setting the *ngFor* as carousel-item, it doesn't work because it requires active class. Also, the *item?[0].pin_photos.url* just gets the first picture.

```
   <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="http://MYURL/public/PinPhotos/{{item?.pin_photos[0].url}}"
                    class="d-block w-100 carousel-pic" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div *ngFor="let pic of pics">
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="http://MYURL/public/PinPhotos/{{pic.url}}" class="d-block w-100 carousel-pic" alt="...">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 4):

I use `ngFor` first variable to set the class for the first item

*template*

```js
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"  *ngFor="let item of items;let index = index" [attr.data-slide-to]="index"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item" *ngFor="let item of items;let index = index;let isFirst = first" [ngClass]="{active:isFirst}">
      <img [src]="item.url" class="d-block w-100" [alt]="item.title">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5 [textContent]="item.title"></h5>
        <p [textContent]="item.symmery"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

trigger carousel manualy like this

```
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    $('#carouselExampleCaptions').carousel()
  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e623zb)

Answer (score 3):

I think ngFor will modify you html tree.

try to use:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let pic of pics">
```

instead:

```
<div *ngFor="let pic of pics">
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you try this , it uses `ngClass` to set only first item in the list to active.

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" #mycarouselControls class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
    <div class="carousel-inner">                
            <ul *ngFor="let pic of pics;let i=index; first as isFirst">
                <div [ngClass]="isFirst ? 'carousel-item active' : 'carousel-item' ">
                    <li><img src={{pic}} class="d-block w-100 carousel-pic" alt="..."></li>
                </div>                                     
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the easiest approach :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use **OnPush change detection**, so create a dumb component.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-carousel-items',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    template: `<div *ngFor="let pic of pics">
                 <div class="carousel-item">
                   <img src="http://MYURL/public/PinPhotos/{{pic.url}}" class="d-block w-100 carousel-pic" alt="...">
                 </div>
               </div>`,
})
export class CarouselItemsComponent  {
  @Input('pictures') pictures; // pass your pictures from this input  
}
```

Now your loop will not start again.

Comment: I think mention onPush her is a great tip  but app-carousel-items will create a new wrapper item I don't know if this will work so far this is a jquery world now  or we may need to trigger carousel manual

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

First, you are applying the `active` class on every `carousel-item`. To remedy that, we need to remove the hard-coded class from the template and add it dynamically to the first item. Luckily we can get the index with the help of `ngFor` and apply it to the first item using `ngClass`.

Next, for your `carousel-indicators` you have it left static with three indicators, hence only three navigator buttons shown and the issues with carousel getting stuck. To fix that we can use `ngFor` again on indicator items, bind the index to `data-slide-to`, and like we did before, set the `active` class to the first item using `ngClass`.

I use Bootstrap 5 but adapted the code to **Bootstrap 4** so this should work.

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li *ngFor="let pic of pics; let i = index" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" [attr.data-slide-to]="i" [ngClass]="{'active': i == 0}"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div *ngFor="let pic of pics; let i = index" class="carousel-item" [ngClass]="{'active': i == 0}">
            <img src="http://MYURL/public/PinPhotos/{{pic.url}}" class="d-block w-100 carousel-pic" alt="...">
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>

</div>
```

For anyone looking for **Bootstrap 5** solution, it is very similar:

```
<div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">

    <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button *ngFor="let url of picUrls; let i = index" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" [attr.data-bs-slide-to]="i" aria-current="true" aria-label="..." [ngClass]="{'active': i == 0}">
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div *ngFor="let url of picUrls; let i = index" class="carousel-item" [ngClass]="{'active': i == 0}">
            <img src="{{url}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>First slide label</h5>
                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>

</div>
```